# Can an instrument procedure be intercepted from the middle and how?

Tags: air-traffic-control, regulations, instrument-procedures

While I was reading [FAA-H-8083-6](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/advanced_avionics_handbook/) I was wondering if a pilot can be instructed to intercept a procedure from a point somewhere in the middle of it.

Specifically:

A pilot departs from an airport having assigned the FOBAR1 SID. There is RADAR service, hence after departure they are vectored to a position outside of that SID. Can the ATC instruct for any reason the pilot to resume the SID? And if this can be done, how is it done? Simply `Resume FOBAR1 SID` or more specifically eg `Fly heading 125, resume FOBAR1 SID` or `Proceed direct ABC, resume FOBAR1 SID`?

**NOTE** While I mention an FAA document I am *mostly* interested for EASA and/or ICAO regulations/procedures.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer is yes.

### FAA

ATC Section 6. Vectoring:

> When vectoring or approving an aircraft to deviate off of a procedure that includes published altitude restrictions, advise the pilot if you intend on clearing the aircraft to resume the procedure.
>
> PHRASEOLOGY−
>
> > FLY HEADING (degrees), MAINTAIN (altitude), EXPECT TO RESUME (SID, STAR, etc.).
> >
> > ---
> >
> > DEVIATION (restrictions if necessary) APPROVED, MAINTAIN (altitude) EXPECT TO RESUME (SID, STAR, etc.) AT (NAVAID, fix, waypoint).
>
> NOTE− After a Climb Via or Descend Via clearance has been issued, a vector/deviation off of a SID/STAR cancels the altitude restrictions on the procedure. The aircraft’s Flight Management System (FMS) may be unable to process crossing altitude restrictions once the aircraft leaves the SID/STAR lateral path. Without an assigned altitude, the aircraft’s FMS may revert to leveling off at the altitude set by the pilot, which may be the SID/STAR’s published top or bottom altitude.
>
> > (Position with respect to course/fix along route), **RESUME OWN NAVIGATION,** FLY HEADING (degrees).
> >
> > ---
> >
> > WHEN ABLE, PROCEED DIRECT (name of fix), RESUME (SID/STAR/transition/procedure).

### ICAO

eurocontrol.int quotes ICAO Doc4444, 15th edition 2007:

**12.4.1.4**

> **RESUME OWN NAVIGATION** [DIRECT] (significant point) [MAGNETIC TRACK (three digits) DISTANCE (number) KILOMETRES (or MILES)].

**12.3.2.1**

> JOIN (specify) AT (significant point) AT (level) [AT (time)].
>
> Example: LGL123 join upper golf 1 at GORLU at FL330 at time three two.